# Parenthesis balance program crashing(c)

Tags: c

Good afternoon, i am trying to do a program that checks whether if a expression has its parentheses balanced or not but because of some problem that i can't quite find out the program is crashing, could somebody help me find a way so that the program works?

```
In

a * b - (2 + c)

Out

Correct
```

or

```
In

)3+b * (2-c)(

Out

Incorrect
```

The program should check only for parantheses and i am supposed to implement linear lists on the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SUCESSO 1 //Succes
#define FALHA -1 //Failure
#define CELULA_INVALIDA 0 //Invalid key

#define TAMANHO_MAXIMO 1000 //Max size

typedef struct{
    char exp[1000];
    unsigned int chave; //key
}celula; //node

typedef struct{
    celula celulas[TAMANHO_MAXIMO]; //vector of nodes
    unsigned int tamanho; //size of the list
}fila; //list

int criarFilaVazia(fila * ent){ //create an empty list
    ent->tamanho = 0;
    return(SUCESSO);
}

int insFinal(fila * ent, celula node){ //put a node on the end of the list
    unsigned int i;
    celula aux;

    if(ent->tamanho == TAMANHO_MAXIMO){
        return(FALHA);
    }
    else{
        ent->celulas[ent->tamanho] = node;
        ent->tamanho++;
        return(SUCESSO);
    }
}

void mostrarCelula(celula ent){ //show node
    printf("%s \n", ent.exp);
}

void mostrarFila(fila ent){ //show entire list
    unsigned int i;

    if(ent.tamanho == 0){
        printf("Fila vazia");
    }
    else{
        printf("A fila possui %u element \n", ent.tamanho);
        for(i=0; (i < ent.tamanho); i++){
            printf("Elemento %u \n \n", (i+1));
            mostrarCelula(ent.celulas[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i, j;
    fila exp;
    celula aux;

    scanf("%s", &aux.exp);
    getchar();
    aux.chave = 0;

    insFinal(&exp, aux);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(exp.celulas[0].exp); i++){//checks all the array
        if(exp.celulas[0].exp[i] == '('){//if there is an opening
            for(j = i; j < strlen(exp.celulas[0].exp); j++){
                if(exp.celulas[0].exp[j] == ')'){//should be and ending
                    exp.celulas[0].exp[i] = 0;//removes if balanced
                    exp.celulas[0].exp[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //checks for remaining parentheses and prints the output
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(exp.celulas[0].exp); i++){
        if(exp.celulas[0].exp[i] == '(' || exp.celulas[0].exp[i] == ')'){
            printf("Incorreta"); //incorrect
        }
        else{
            printf("Correta"); //correct
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

Error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeSn5.png
  it says ex06 stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is crashing inside `insFinal` because the `ent` parameter passed in from `main` has uninitialized data.  Hence, undefined behavior. Ammend these two lines at the beginning of `main`:

```
fila exp;
celula aux;
```

With this:

```
fila exp = {0};
celula aux = {0};
```

That will zero-init both.

The thing I don't get is what all these data structures are used for.  Nor do I understand the double-nested for loop for checking the balance.  Checking for a balanced set of parentheses in an expression should be as simple as this:

```
int areParenthesesBalanced(const char* str) 
{
    int balance = 0;
    int len = str ? strlen(str) : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '(')
        {
            balance++;
        }
        else if (str[i] == ')')
        {
            balance--;
            if (balance < 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return (balance == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main() {
    char str[1000];
    scanf("%s", str);
    if (areParenthesesBalanced(str))
    {
        printf("Incorreta\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Correta\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping me with that question. I am really new to programming in c(this exercise is for one of the very first classes of my High school), the data structures are because of pure demand of my professor and i really need as much points as possible on this class and this way of checking the balance is really nice, unfortunately i was not able to figure it out alone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to upvote the answer if it helps. And if you think it works, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: I upvoted it, but it says that it won't change the counter.

Comment: Your answear solved my problem but now the program only works when it has spaces on the input. I only used your first tip(the uninitialied structure one) since the second one didn't quite worked with my program.

Comment: That `getchar` call you do consumes the leading character in the input stream. Remove it.